# Supplying a Lambda Expression Using Multiple Tables as a Parameter in an Entity Framework Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In my Entity Framework base repository, I've added a method that can be supplied a lambda function called `RemoveWhere`. In many cases, it works fine. It does not work, however, when the lambda function includes a table other than the one for the higher-level repository that specifies TEntity. Similarly, it doesn't work if a variable with other table records is supplied. Is there a way to adjust either the lambda function that is supplied or the method to allow such lambda functions to be used?

Here's the base repository with the `RemoveWhere` method:

```cs
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
    }

    public void RemoveWhere(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        List<TEntity> someRecords = Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToList();
        if (someRecords == null || someRecords.Count == 0) return;

        Context.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(someRecords);

        return;
    }
}
```

`GetAll()` for a separate table, which is used in the client class example below is in a higher-level repository:

```cs
internal class AnotherTableRepository : Repository<AnotherTable>
{
        ...
        public IEnumerable<AnotherTable> GetAll()
        {
            return ssxProjectContext.AnotherTables.Where(u => u.Deleted == false).ToList();
        }
}
```

I didn't include the unit of work class. It would be pretty standard for Entity Framework,defining `AnotherTables` and `SomeTables`.

Below would be from the client class. I want to supply the function shown.

```cs
IEnumerable<AnotherTable> anotherTable = unitOfWork.AnotherTables.GetAll().Where(x => x.ColumnOne == "SomeValue");

//The function supplied does not work because it includes a variable of records from another table
IEnumerable<SomeTable> someTable = unitOfWork.SomeTables.RemoveWhere(x => anotherTable.Any(y => y.KeyColumn == x.KeyColumn));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF generates effective queries from `IQueryable`, so keep `IQueryable` as long as possible. It means do not call `ToList`, `ToArray`, `AsEnumerable`, etc.

```cs
var anotherTable = unitOfWork.AnotherTables.GetAll()
    .Where(x => x.ColumnOne == "SomeValue");

var someTable = unitOfWork.SomeTables
    .RemoveWhere(x => anotherTable.Any(y => y.KeyColumn == x.KeyColumn));
```

Anyway your query also should work, but instead of `Any` you should use `Contains`, but remember that it is less effective:

```cs
var someTable = unitOfWork.SomeTables
    .RemoveWhere(x => anotherTable.Select(y => y.KeyColumn).Contains(x.KeyColumn));
```

Comment: Are you suggesting keeping my code as-is except use `Contains` instead?

Comment: I tried casting `AnotherTable` as IQueryable, but I received an error "Unable to cast of of type 'WhereListerIterator'..." Not sure if this is what you're thinking when you mean keep IQueryable as long as possible, but I thought I'd mention it. Could you add some clarity on what you mean by "keep IQueryable as long as possible"?

Comment: You should not cast IEnumerable to IQueryable, it has no sense. Show your GetAll implementation. If it do not return IQueryable - you fail.

Comment: Using `IQueryable<T>` is also a reason to dispense with mindless `ToList()` calls that prevent composability. It's excellent that you removed them and I think you might want to mention it.

Comment: Corrected answer. I thought it is obvious.

Comment: OK. I've got it. The `GetAll()` method was developed from an example template and returned an `IEnumerable` and used `ToLIst()`. Changing the return type to `IQueryable` seems to have solved it. I've added `GetAll()` to the question. Maybe you want to update the answer to point specifically to the problem with it.

Comment: Please don't create generic repository, it has no sense with EF. Just another dumb abstraction [Is the repository pattern useful with Entity Framework Core?](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/).

Comment: The repository pattern allows me to centralize code in the business layer without affecting EF's DAL layer. Better to update and use BL and DAL layers separately.